# Open Office 3.3: how to make OOo not remember the export-as-pdf path

Tags: pdf, openoffice

... but instead suggest the path of the opened document?

Comment: I've noticed this problem too, and it's also present in earlier versions as well.  This may be a bug that needs to be reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Open Office select *Tools* -> *Options*. On the *OpenOffice.org/General* page, select the option **Use OpenOffice.org dialogs**. This will cause the right path be preselected.